# List of Objects with python

Tags: python, list, class

I have a function that return list of objects named `Query`.
The function find all the `pkl` files in the directory, and then serialize the files.
The code:

```
from Query import Query
def createQueryArr():
    qry = []
    os.chdir(CONST_QUERY_DIR)
    for queryFile in os.listdir("."):
        if queryFile.endswith(".pkl"):
            pkl_file = open(queryFile, 'rb')
            qry = pickle.load(pkl_file)
            pkl_file.close()
            queryArr.append(qry)
    return queryArr
```

however, the return array contain distorted data.
When iterating the array, and print each object, 0 and 1 are printed.
`Query` implements `__str__(self)`
The iterating code:

```
arr = createQueryArr()
for qry in range(len(arr)):
    print(qry)
```

Comment: What's your question? You don't seem to be asking anything.

Comment: The return array contain distorted data, what is my mistake?

Comment: What do you mean by "distorted data"? What results do you see?

Comment: How were the `.pkl` files created? Can you show the code that produced them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part:

```
for qry in range(len(arr)):
```

iterates over the indices of `arr`, not the elements. Thus, this part:

```
print(qry)
```

prints the indices. You want

```
for qry in arr:
    print(qry)
```

or `print qry` if you're on Python 2.

Comment: Even if you're on python 2, it doesn't do any damage to include the parenthesis as well. Makes it easier for the transition later :)

Comment: @twall: If you do, it'll confuse people and cause bugs when you write `print(a, b)`. If you want to use parentheses, use a future statement to access the print function.